# Confused on deciding whether its Negative Binomial or Binomial and Negative Hypergeometric or Geometric

Tags: random-variables, binomial-theorem, hypergeometric-function

I am currently struggling on deciding whether a question is a Negative binomial or a Binomial, and Negative Hypergeometric or a Hypergeometric SRV (Special Random Variable), As I seem to always switched up between either of those two....  Are there any kind of difference/ clues so that we know its SRV type? Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated thank you :D

Comment: What does SRV stand for? I assume RV stands for "random variable", but what's the S?

Comment: @littleO Sorry for the misunderstanding, but Its a Special Random Variable